# Counting spanning trees and hamiltonian paths

Tags: graph-theory, trees

Assumption : For any connected graph, every hamiltonian path is a spanning tree but not the other way around.

If the assumption is wrong there is no need of reading any furhter. So is the assumption correct ?

We have numerous algorithms to find all spanning trees of a connected graph. So, according to the assumption, haven't we already found all hamiltonian paths and thus MAYBE all hamiltonian circuits ?

If the above statements are correct, are we verifying(NP) the solution or are we finding(P) it ?

Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes what you said its true - given a graph $G$ its a hamiltonian path is a spanning tree of $G$ and not every spanning tree of $G$ is a hamiltonian path.

With respect to what you say later on, we do have efficient algorithms for **counting** the number of spanning trees not finding all of them. Indeed the number of spanning trees is in general an exponential quantity hence there is no chance of having a efficient (polynomial time) algorithm for this problem.

Comment: But we can find all spanning trees using cyclic exchanges ? can we not ? @Jernej

Comment: Yes but there are exponentially many ways in which you can do these exchanges.